# How do I get rid of boxed '?' symbols that appear after every character in tmux?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tmux

When I run tmux, every character has a boxed '?' next to it. The boxed '?' symbols also appear after every character I type when I am within vim when I am in tmux. I have been doing research online about how to alter my ~/.vimrc and ~/.bashrc files but am having a difficult time finding the exact solution to my question. Nothing I have added to ~/.tmux.conf has seemed to do anything so I no longer have any code there.

I am running an Ubuntu bash shell on a Windows 10 operating system. To clarify, I am running Ubuntu as a graphic application using the Windows subsystem. I am not emulating it.

Here is what my hello.cpp file looks like when I try to insert any code in to it. This happens when I try to write a hello.java file as well. Does anyone have any insight?

[image]

.vimrc:

```
:set backspace=ident,eol,start

syntax on
:hightlight Comment ctermfg=23
```

My additions to .bashrc:

```
echo "Welcome back"

cd ~/../../mnt/c

alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"

...
(default code)
```

Comment: Are you typing soma particular character when the boxes appear, like tab?

Comment: CMD and PowerShell are _not terminal emulators_.  The terminal emulator would be something like Windows Terminal.  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/a-command-interpreter-is-not-a-console.html

Comment: No, it can be any character.

Comment: Have you tried changing the font in your terminal? Check if it works with `DejaVu Sans Mono` for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is a problem with your terminal rather than any application (tmux, bash, vim). A guess would be it is sending UTF-16 for key presses instead of UTF-8. I suggest you try a different terminal (putty?) and if the problem goes away then report this to the developers of your terminal. You might have luck poking about in the settings for the terminal looking for keyboard options.

Also, you should not use TERM of `screen` outside tmux - use whatever is right for your terminal (often `xterm` even in terminals that aren't xterm). Use `screen` or `tmux` inside tmux. But I don't think this is related to your problem.

Comment: I don't know how I would use another terminal considering that I am not emulating Ubuntu, I am running it as a graphic application using the windows subsystem.

Comment: @DarienSpringer You can run `sshd` and then choose `localhost` as the host name in Putty. See details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10) for instance.